# How to show a popup to a user only once

Tags: php, html, cookies, popup, materialize

I want to add a popup to my website!

I want the popup to apper only once per user and should be dismissable .If the user closes the popup the popup can be again opened using a button click if the visitor is interested to rate the service.

How to do that? 
I'm using materize css , i tried modal but it opens each time the website is loaded

Comment: If you have the users logged in, the best way would be to store this in your database. It's the only reliable way of doing it. Using cookies or browser storage means that the user will get the message when they use a different browser, when they use a different device or when they simply clear all offline files.

Comment: I'm not using a login system for the site

Answer (score 0):

You will need to track information of which user was the popup already shown.

Keep the info on client side such as cookie or server side such as session/profile.

[Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)

[Window.localStorage MDN web doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: How can i do that using cookie or local storage, whichever is reliable

Comment: @VithulTNair I have updated my answer with links to reference

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable which stores the weather the popup for the user has been opened or not. Store this variable in the browser cookies.

Comment: Can you please explain me in detail as I'm a newbie